# Getting A Selected Object from GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am fairly new to ASP.NET. I have a term project; the issue I am facing is described as follows:

- I have a page named Contacts.
- I have a class called User.
- I have an ArrayList of `User` which is bound as a datasource to a Gridview in
  `Contacts`.

What I want to do is that when I click on a contact from the gridview, I want a new page to open which will give details of the selected contact. For that I need the contact in a `Session` Variable.

My problem is that I do not know how to "extract" the selected object from the GridView. I tried the event `SelectedIndexChanged` but that isn't working because the response isn't redirected to the new page.

I have considered making one Column of the GV a Hyperlink Field, but that will redirect response to a new page only. It doesn't store the selected contact in a session variable.

Edit: (code)

**HTML**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVV2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
Height="25px"style="margin-right: 4px" Width="616px" 
    onselectedindexchanged="GVV2_SelectedIndexChanged"  >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="checkBoxCell" />
            <ItemStyle CssClass="checkBoxCell" />
            <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FullName_" HeaderText="Name">
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="SenderCell" />
        <ItemStyle CssClass="SenderCell" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="EmailID_" HeaderText="Email ID" 
            NavigateUrl="~/ViewContact1.aspx" >
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="emailCell" />
        <ItemStyle CssClass="emailCell a.decor" />
        </asp:HyperLinkField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public partial class Contacts1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Storage1 STO;
    String currentUser;
    Users1 selectedUser;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Initiation();
        GVV2.DataSource = Contact.getContactList(currentUser, STO);
        GVV2.DataBind();
    }
    private void Initiation()
    {
        if (Session["SignInUser"] == null)
            Session["SignInUser"] = currentUser;
        else currentUser= (String)Session["SignInUser"];`

        if (Session["Storage"] == null)
            Session["Storage"] = STO;
        else
        {
            STO= new Storage1();
            STO = (Storage1)Session["Storage"];
        }

    }

    protected void GVV2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["SelectedContact"]=GVV2.SelectedRow;
        Response.Redirect("ViewContact1.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide som code:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using link button**

Another way to do it is using gridview OnRowCommand instead of onselectedindexchanged.

Use linkbutton to redirect you to desired page. As a command argument you have to pass users ID.

```
<asp:TemplateField> 
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:LinkButton ID="linkBtnDetails" runat="server" Text="Details" CommandName="Details" 
           CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>' /> 
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Also you have to define onrowcommand for the gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVV2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
Height="25px"style="margin-right: 4px" Width="616px" 
    onrowcommand="UserDetails_RowCommand"  >
```

And finally code behind where you will get user's ID, set it to session variable and redirect to page.

```
void UserDetails_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
  if(e.CommandName=="Details")
  {
    Session["SelectedContact"]=e.CommandArgument;
        Response.Redirect("ViewContact1.aspx");
  }
  }
```

**Using hyperlink field**

Send ID in query string.

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="EmailID_" HeaderText="Email ID" 
            NavigateUrl="~/ViewContact1.aspx?id="+"<%#Eval('ID')%>" >
```

In the code behind on the page load get the id like this:

```
string getUserID = Request.QueryString["id"];
int userID = Convert.ToInt32(getUserID);
```

Comment: what if I dont want to use a link button? Then what should I do?

Comment: Which control do you want to use?

Comment: I want to use Hyperlink

Comment: The hyperlink detail is given below. I will use that. But thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: I've edited my post so you can see how to do it with hyperlink!

Comment: Ok thats really nice of you. I will see.

Comment: So Im using the `userID` to access my `Contact`? Meaning that the ID is unique to all users?

Comment: But if it is the email ID, then it IS unique. So, how can I access it as a String?

Comment: If email ID is unique, then you send it in query string and get it in code behind.

Answer (score 1):

**1º Way:**
Pass a QueryString parameter with the value that you need on the redirected page, in this case, it could be the user code. Obviously, you can't pass the `User` object on this case, but you could obtain the `User` details on the target page.

```
<asp:TemplateField> 
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:Hyperlink ID="hplViewDetails" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("userCode", "~ViewContact1.aspx?userCode={0}")%>' Text="Details" /> 
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

To retrieve the value on the redirected page:

```
int userCode = Convert.ToInt32(Request["userCode"]);
```

**2º Way:** implement the `IPostBackEventHandler` interface on your page.

Put an HyperLink that points to a javascript function:

```
<asp:TemplateField> 
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:Hyperlink ID="hplViewDetails" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("userCode", "javascript:redirectToUserDetails({0})")%>' /> 
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This function will trigger the postback to your page:

```
<script>
    function redirectToUserDetails(userCode)
    {
        __doPostBack('<%= ClientID %>', userCode);
    }
<script>
```

And the Postback method will do the proper redirect (`RaisePostBackEvent` Method):

```
public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
{
    int userCode = Convert.ToInt32(eventArgument);
    User user = GetUserFromSession(userCode);
    string userObjectKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    Session[userObjectKey] = user;
    Response.Redirect(string.Format("~/ViewContact1.aspx?userObjectKey={0}", userObjectKey);
}
```

On ViewContact1.aspx, retrieve the object:

```
User user = (User)Session["userObjectKey"];
```

This could also be made using a dummy button on the page to cause a postback to the server.